# Dash/Flask Python App Azure Deployment: Application object must be callable

Tags: python, azure, flask, deployment, gunicorn

so I'm trying to deploy my Dash app onto Azure using Azure Web App.  When I use the "Github Actions" method of deployment, I get the following (I even made my repository public for this):

```
Package deployment using ZIP Deploy initiated.
##[error]Failed to deploy web package to App Service.
##[error]Deployment Failed with Error: Error: Failed to deploy web package to App Service.
Unauthorized (CODE: 401)
##[warning]Error: Failed to update deployment history.
Unauthorized (CODE: 401)
App Service Application URL: http://my-site.azurewebsites.net
```

I've also tried deploying with "Kudu App Build" instead of the Github Actions and that "deploys successfully", giving me a status of "Success(Active)" but once I go to my website it fails, then when I go to **Diagnosis and solve problems** in the azure portal I receive the following error:

```
2020-06-05T14:32:08.567155259Z 
2020-06-05T14:32:08.567159059Z Documentation: http://aka.ms/webapp-linux
2020-06-05T14:32:08.567163159Z Python 3.8.0
2020-06-05T14:32:08.567166959Z Note: Any data outside '/home' is not persisted
2020-06-05T14:32:09.126144120Z Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server: sshd.
2020-06-05T14:32:09.177989757Z Site's appCommandLine: gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0 --timeout 600 application:app
2020-06-05T14:32:09.179066899Z Launching oryx with: -appPath /home/site/wwwroot -output /opt/startup/startup.sh -virtualEnvName antenv -defaultApp /opt/defaultsite -userStartupCommand 'gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0 --timeout 600 application:app'
2020-06-05T14:32:09.289253728Z Oryx Version: 0.2.20200114.13, Commit: 204922f30f8e8d41f5241b8c218425ef89106d1d, ReleaseTagName: 20200114.13
2020-06-05T14:32:09.315423056Z Found build manifest file at '/home/site/wwwroot/oryx-manifest.toml'. Deserializing it...
2020-06-05T14:32:09.322220623Z Build Operation ID: |mqhAw8K+i4s=.a5925a0c_
2020-06-05T14:32:09.937709104Z Writing output script to '/opt/startup/startup.sh'
2020-06-05T14:32:10.656204831Z Found virtual environment .tar.gz archive.
2020-06-05T14:32:10.656991662Z Removing existing virtual environment directory /antenv...
2020-06-05T14:32:10.667494675Z Extracting to directory /antenv...
2020-06-05T14:32:42.888599159Z Using packages from virtual environment antenv located at /antenv.
2020-06-05T14:32:42.891102058Z Updated PYTHONPATH to ':/antenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages'
2020-06-05T14:32:44.966320399Z [2020-06-05 14:32:44 +0000] [42] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
2020-06-05T14:32:44.973255871Z [2020-06-05 14:32:44 +0000] [42] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (42)
2020-06-05T14:32:44.974184808Z [2020-06-05 14:32:44 +0000] [42] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2020-06-05T14:32:45.047728498Z [2020-06-05 14:32:45 +0000] [44] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 44
2020-06-05T14:32:50.315649084Z Application object must be callable.
2020-06-05T14:32:50.321677821Z [2020-06-05 14:32:50 +0000] [44] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 44)
2020-06-05T14:32:50.630621560Z [2020-06-05 14:32:50 +0000] [42] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2020-06-05T14:32:50.630656561Z [2020-06-05 14:32:50 +0000] [42] [INFO] Reason: App failed to load.
```

That was the application error, here is the container error

```
Please use https://aka.ms/linux-diagnostics to enable logging to see container logs here.
2020-06-05T14:30:22.831Z INFO  - Initiating warmup request to container my-site_0_06a70784 for site my-site
2020-06-05T14:30:38.890Z INFO  - Waiting for response to warmup request for container my-site_0_06a70784. Elapsed time = 16.0594968 sec
2020-06-05T14:30:54.492Z INFO  - Waiting for response to warmup request for container my-site_0_06a70784. Elapsed time = 31.6616936 sec
2020-06-05T14:31:09.663Z ERROR - Container my-site_0_06a70784 for site my-site has exited, failing site start
2020-06-05T14:31:09.695Z ERROR - Container my-site_0_06a70784 didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8000, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.
2020-06-05T14:31:10.217Z INFO  - Stopping site my-site because it failed during startup.
2020-06-05T14:31:11.646Z INFO  - Starting container for site
2020-06-05T14:31:11.647Z INFO  - docker run -d -p 4040:8000 --name my-site_0_9c00d1f9 -e WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=my-site -e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=False -e WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e WEBSITE_HOSTNAME=my-site.azurewebsites.net -e WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=b78e390e9ef390f579e4e316c4d4ea6c7f187e4af48b856ebd3562fda3c5ef4f appsvc/python:3.8_20200101.1 gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0 --timeout 600 application:app
```

Here is what my application.py looks like (I've tried several variations of this to no avail):

```
 import app as application
 app = application.app

 if __name__ == "__main__":
     app.run_server(debug=False)
```

And at the top of my app.py file I have:

```
 app = dash.Dash(__name__)
```

This is my requirements.txt:

```
 bs4==0.0.1
 dash==1.12.0
 dash-table==4.7.0
 Flask==1.1.2
 numpy==1.18.0
 pandas==1.0.4
 requests==2.12.4
```

Lastly, this is the startup command I use in the **Configuration->General Settings->Startup Command**

```
 gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0 --timeout 600 application:app
```

Answer (score 1):

The application you should run when deployment is `dash.Dash.server`(in your case it's `app.server`), it's the underly Flask application. So, you have to update the second line of your application.py to this:

```
app = application.server
```

See more in [Dash docs](https://dash.plotly.com/deployment).