# Problem with Deploying Dash app to an Azure Web App

Tags: python, azure-web-app-service, plotly-dash

I am trying to deploy an open source dash app to an azure web app. The app is working fine locally. There are no problems while deployment as well. The environment gets built and the app gets deployed without any errors but when I visit the webpage I get a message saying **Application Error**.

I tried deploying just the layout, that didn't work.

I tried adding **gunicorn** to the requirements.txt and added **"gunicorn application:app.server -b :8000"** this command to **Startup Command** under **Configuration>General Settings** in the azure portal.

This is a link to a github page with the complete code and setup:
https://github.com/KishoreKB2711/StockApp

Answer (score 0):

- To run the deployed  **Flask**  application, we have to add few settings in your App service=> Settings =>Configuration =>Application Settings=> Click on Add new application settings and add the settings:

```py
1. SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT=1
2. WEBSITES_CONTAINER_START_TIME_LIMIT=1800
3. WEBSITES_PORT=<port_number_of_your_application>
```

[image]

Use the gunicorn command in Startup command of App Service:
`gunicorn app:server`
(or)
`gunicorn application:server`

[image]

`application/app` refer to *filename* `application.py / app.py` and `server` is the *variable* name used inside `app.py`. Refer [dash docs](https://dash.plotly.com/deployment) and [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62217892/dash-flask-python-app-azure-deployment-application-object-must-be-callable).

I had a similar issue for flask application, it worked after following the above-mentioned steps. Refer [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76742725/python-flask-application-in-azure-web-app-only-showing-default-page/76744641#76744641).

To know the cause of the error, check the logs of App service:

- Enable logging in Web App=>App Service Logs:

[image]

- Track the logs in Log Stream of App Service

Answer (score 0):

This has been a road block for some time now. Finally found an article that deployed dash apps to azure using docker. Please find the link to the article below:

https://www.phillipsj.net/posts/deploying-dash-to-azure-app-service/

Thank you for your answers. Cheers

Comment: not useful tried almost everything... it is always looking for something to run on 8000 but I do not know why