# Python flask application in Azure web app only showing default page

Tags: python, azure, flask, web-applications, default

I have been struggling for days to deploy a Python web app with flask on Azure. But all I ever get is the default page.

This is the address: https://el-priser.azurewebsites.net/
This is my Github repo: https://github.com/Michaelgimm/energinet-elpris

I also tried with the azure guide for a test app, but it does the same.

The deployment is a success and I can see all the files when accessing through SSH via this link: https://el-priser.**scm**.azurewebsites.net/

Any ideas?

I haave tried everything I can think of. What I did expect to see was my app.
In the structure of my app I have a main.py but placed the index.html in a folder called templates.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to deploy your application to Azure web app through VScode.

I could deploy the application, but I was able to see only ***default page*** and few times it also led me to ***Application Error.***

[image]

- After many trials, I could figure out the resolution for this issue.
- To run the deployed **Flask** application, we have to add few settings in the web app.
- **Go to your App service=> Settings =>Configuration =>Application Settings=> Click on Add new application settings and add the settings:**

```
1. SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT=1
2. WEBSITES_CONTAINER_START_TIME_LIMIT=1800
3. WEBSITES_PORT=<port_number_of_your_application>
```

[image]

- Go to **General Settings** in **Configuration** of your *web app* and add the **startup command** `gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0 main:app`.
- As your Flask app main module is `main.py` and the Flask app object in that file is named as `app`, use the above given *Startup* command.

[image]

- Restart the web app after adding all these settings.
- Now, you will be able to access your application (index and prices pages):

**Response:**

I could access both the index and prices pages as shown below:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had actually just installed VS Code and did most of the same here: https://energinet-elpriser.azurewebsites.net/
I guess VS Code is better suited for Azure than PyCharm due to some settings already being in place :-)

Comment: Startup command 
"gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0:8000 main:app"

as 8000 is default webapp container port