# Deploying fastAPI in Azure

Tags: python, azure, azure-web-app-service, fastapi

I am trying to deploy my application which is built using Python and FastAPI for backend and the HTML for the frontend.

Using the student login i created an app service and uploaded my code using github.

My project directory is like

```
Frontend/
|- file.html
|- x.css
FastAPI/
|- main.py
|- other.py
|- requirements.txt
```

in my .yml files, I changed the directory of the requirements.txt and package in deploy to ./fastAPI. But the website url shows the following message.

> Hey, Python developers!
>
> Your app service is up and running. Time to take the next step and
> deploy your code.

And it displays the error message in github workflow

> Deployment Failed, Error: Failed to deploy web package to App Service.
> Conflict (CODE: 409)

I tried to use startup-command in the yml file to start the FastAPI, it didn't work and gave the following error message

> Deployment Failed, Error: startup-command is not a valid input for
> Windows web app or with publish-profile auth scheme.

I changed the configuration on the azure portal to add `WEBSITES_CONTAINER_STARTUP_COMMAND = uvicorn main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 80` in the application settings, didn't work.

Comment: Please provide your GitHub repository link if you don't have any sensitive information.

Comment: Hey! There are a few keys which are required for the app to run.

Comment: Please replace those keys with any random value/variable and provide code link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have deployed a simple Fast API project with HTML and CSS as frontend:

**My project structure:**

```
- FastAPI
    - templates
        - index.html
    -static
        - style.css
    - main.py
    - requirements.txt
```

- Create **Azure App Service** with **Python** as Runtime stack, **Linux** as OS and **Consumption** hosting Plan in **Azure Portal**:

[image]

- Configure Deployment during the creation of App Service.

[image]

- Click on `Review+Create`.
- Once the App Service gets created, it will generate the workflow in your GitHub repository, and it starts the deployment.
- Deployment status can be tracked in your `GitHub repository=>Actions`.

**My Workflow to deploy FastAPI:**

```yaml
name: Build and deploy Python app to Azure Web App - <web_app_Name>

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up Python version
        uses: actions/setup-python@v1
        with:
          python-version: '3.10'

      - name: Create and start virtual environment
        run: |
          python -m venv venv
          source venv/bin/activate
      
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: pip install -r requirements.txt
        
      # Optional: Add step to run tests here (PyTest, Django test suites, etc.)
      
      - name: Upload artifact for deployment jobs
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: python-app
          path: |
            . 
            !venv/
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: python-app
          path: .
          
      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        with:
          app-name: '<web_app_Name>'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_XXXXXXXXXXX }}
Ad
```

**Deployed Successfully:**

[image]

You have to run the Startup command for FastAPI in App Service=>Settings=>Configuration:
`gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0 main:app`

- `main` is from the filename `main.py` and app is the object which I used in `main.py`.

[image]

**References:**

Refer my [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76742725/python-flask-application-in-azure-web-app-only-showing-default-page/76744641#76744641) on the similar issue.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, I refered to some documents and followed similar steps to deploy the fastapi app, the problem is that the website is not loading only now :/
Ill try the "Add new application settings". Unfortunately I cannot share the code with you but I do appreciate you help!

Comment: gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0 main:app, if my main.py file is in fastAPI/main.py will this command change? This is the only thing I can think of

Comment: Try with `gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0 fastAPI. main:app`